# Unable to set state with useState hook with function call

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I have set my initial state object like this:

```
const [Item,SetItem] = useState(
        {
            description: "Chicken",
            foodNutrients:[
            {nutrientName: "Protein", nutrientNumber: "203", value: 10},
            {nutrientName: "Fat", nutrientNumber: "204",  value: 15},
            {nutrientName: "Carbs", nutrientNumber: "205", value: 20}
            ]
        }
    )
```

I want to modify my existing object by looping through foodNutrient array and doubling the value on button click, then storing the updated object in useState hook.

```
 const Double = e => {
        SetItem(Item.foodNutrients.forEach(foodNutrient => foodNutrient.value *= 2))
        console.log(Item)
    }
```

it logs the correct result to the console first time I try to click `<button onClick={Double}>Set state</button>`, but the second time it throws `Cannot read property 'foodNutrients' of undefined` and I cant render anything.

Comment: React state is commonly supposed to be immutable, it should be immutable in case of `useState` hook. This means that there should be a new object when a state is changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic in your event handler is replacing the initial object with `undefined` because `Array.prototype.forEach` returns `undefined` by default.

What you need to do is:

1. `map` to an array with new values
2. preserve the previous state and set array value in the state to the new maped array

```
const Double = (e) => {
  const foodNutrientsNew = Item.foodNutrients.map((foodNutrient) => ({
    ...foodNutrient,
    value: foodNutrient.value * 2,
  }));
  SetItem((prev) => ({ ...prev, foodNutrients: foodNutrientsNew }));
};
```

**UPDATE**

I would also suggest refactoring your code and splitting it into more components. Just follow the official docs article [here](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

Comment: @EstusFlask agree. fixed

Answer (score 0):

A much better approach is to do this in the onClick handler instead -

```
 const Double = e => {

    // clone your Item object
    const cloneItem = {...Item};

    // now make modifications in the new object
    cloneItem.foodNutrients.forEach(foodNutrient => foodNutrient.value *=2 );      
     
    SetItem(cloneItem);

    // to see the difference in console
    console.log(cloneItem)
    console.log(Item)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of things to help you and i came up with this solution which is working for me.

```
function App() {
  const [item, setItem] = useState({
    description: "Chicken",
    foodNutrients: [
      { nutrientName: "Protein", nutrientNumber: "203", value: 10 },
      { nutrientName: "Fat", nutrientNumber: "204", value: 15 },
      { nutrientName: "Carbs", nutrientNumber: "205", value: 20 },
    ],
  });

  console.log(item);

  const double = (e) => {
    setItem({...item}, item.foodNutrients.map(e => e.value *=2));
  }
  return <button onClick={double}>Set state</button>;
}
```